# Why are ( ) added when using child.nodeValue.replace() with Prototype JS

Tags: replace, prototypejs, parentheses, nodevalue

I am using the following Prototype JS code to replace text:

```
document.body.select('*:not(script)').each(function(el){
  $A(el.childNodes).each(function(child){
    if (child.nodeType === 3) { // only get text nodes
      child.nodeValue = child.nodeValue.replace('an Appointment', 'a Session').replace('Appointment', 'Session').replace('appointment', 'session');
    }
  })
});
```

It has been working, but for some reason, now a `()` is being added after `Request a Session`, which was `Request an Appointment`.

I have not been able to track down the issue. The `()` are not added after any of the other replaced words.

You can view the source of my iframe here: https://acuityscheduling.com/schedule.php?owner=11134756.

Answer (score 1):

The parens seem to be part of the page content. Try disabling javascript and going to the page - you'll see "Pick an Appointment ()"